# What is a Non Existing Process?

Tags: windows-7, windows, process

Today when I woke up my laptop, it was unresponsive but somehow I managed to open procexp. I realized that

- the Image path was not present
- The Parent Process was Non Existing

One interesting thing I noted were three processes synctime.exe that had a decent CPU utilization. I am unable to locate the process image nor can kill it. Google does not return any significant result for synctime.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means process ID 8620 was its parent, but process ID 8620 is no longer running.

You are getting the access denied messages because you are not running Process Explorer as administrator.  There is an option to restart it as administrator in the File menu IIRC.